# Firebase jobdispatcher not triggering within specified window

Tags: android, firebase, job-scheduling, firebase-job-dispatcher

I am implementing Firebase Jobdispatcher with trigger time specified between 10 to 20 seconds. This is my code to schedule a job:

```
public static void scheduleCompatibleJob(Context context) {
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(DataTrackerJobService.class) // the JobService that will be called
            .setTag("api_trigger")
            .setRecurring(true)
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(10, 20)) // 10 to 20 seconds
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
}
```

And the service class:

```
public class DataTrackerJobService extends JobService {
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters job) {
    Log.e("start job", "started " + job);
    (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("handler", "run");
            jobFinished(job, true);
        }
    }, 2000);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters job) {
    Log.e("stop job", "stopped " + job);
    return false;
}
```

}

Job dispatcher is running, but the time in logcat is not correct. With every rescheduling of job, the time gap keeps on increasing, and was never in between 10 to 20 seconds.

> 06-07 11:19:16.429 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/start job: started com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobInvocation@f4250de4
>   06-07 11:19:18.432 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/handler: run
>   06-07 11:20:16.436 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/start job: started com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobInvocation@f16ceb31
>   06-07 11:20:18.438 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/handler: run
>   06-07 11:21:58.519 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/start job: started com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobInvocation@f4c635cd
>   06-07 11:22:00.520 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/handler: run
>   06-07 11:23:40.602 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/start job: started com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobInvocation@f15f8e29
>   06-07 11:23:42.605 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/handler: run
>   06-07 11:25:52.642 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/start job: started com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobInvocation@f48c1045
>   06-07 11:25:54.644 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/handler: run
>   06-07 11:28:52.652 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/start job: started com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobInvocation@f3b49821
>   06-07 11:28:54.655 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/handler: run
>   06-07 11:32:04.688 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/start job: started com.firebase.jobdispatcher.JobInvocation@e7f3c1bd
>   06-07 11:32:06.690 26174-26174/com.example.jobdispatcher E/handler: run

Please check time in logcat. Guide me where am I going wrong in this, or is it supposed to work this way only? Basically I want to implement it for a time gap of 24 hours, but I wonder if this is the working then at one time job will be invoked after double the time specified in the trigger time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at source of Trigger class you'll notice that you have no sure that your job will run at given time.

```java
/**
 * Creates a new ExecutionWindow based on the provided time interval.
 *
 * @param windowStart The earliest time (in seconds) the job should be
 *                    considered eligible to run. Calculated from when the
 *                    job was scheduled (for new jobs) or last run (for
 *                    recurring jobs).
 * @param windowEnd   The latest time (in seconds) the job should be run in
 *                    an ideal world. Calculated in the same way as
 *                    {@code windowStart}.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the provided parameters are too
 *                                  restrictive.
 */
public static JobTrigger.ExecutionWindowTrigger executionWindow(int windowStart, int windowEnd) {
    if (windowStart < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Window start can't be less than 0");
    } else if (windowEnd < windowStart) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Window end can't be less than window start");
    }

    return new JobTrigger.ExecutionWindowTrigger(windowStart, windowEnd);
}
```

You should also note that the next repetitive work is started only when the previous one is over. So when your work is long and expensive, the next execution time may be unexpected. For time consuming jobs you should extend SimpleJobService.

For creating a repeated task I am using my util method that creates a proper Trigger:

```java
public class JobDispatcherUtils {
    public static JobTrigger periodicTrigger(int frequency, int tolerance) {
        return Trigger.executionWindow(frequency - tolerance, frequency);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
class DataTrackerJobService extends SimpleJobService {
    // ...
}

public static void scheduleCompatibleJob(Context context) {
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(DataTrackerJobService.class) // the JobService that will be called
            .setTag("api_trigger")
            .setRecurring(true)
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            .setTrigger(JobDispatcherUtils.periodicTrigger(20, 1)) // repeated every 20 seconds with 1 second of tollerance
            .setReplaceCurrent(true)
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK)
            .build();

    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
}
```

Comment: still not executing within 20 seconds

Comment: but in some chines device like xiaomi   if app clear from task bar job schedule will never work